# Space in Header and Footer?

Tags: html, css

I see a blank space in header and footer I can't find where is a problem.
I am new.

I add on my css but not work:

```
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul, li, blockquote {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}
```

[image: Image header]

[image: Image footer]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I add code but that not fixing my situation what to add hole page or css only code.

Comment: A [mcve] means the smallest amount of code (HTML, JavaScript, CSS) that is necessary to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @JosipValčić I have answered your question below however the code you have added isnt really sufficient. Its good to show how you attempted to fix the issue but In future you should try and add code that allows others to reproduce the issue. Here are the guidelines for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the empty `<p>` tags inside the `<div>` elements with the class `.fl-rich-text` as these have the following style `margin-bottom: 24px;`

If you dont know how to remove these elements then the following CSS should sort you out:

```
main .fl-rich-text > p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I have included main before the `.f1-rich-text` just to improve the specificity of the CSS because I want to make sure it overwrites any CSS you might have effecting it.

Comment: This is the same kind of issue with the footer. Just after the slider with the id `#footer_forcefullwidth`

Comment: I can't find where is on my style.css. I am using WordPress

Comment: @JosipValčić sorry mate im not sure what your asking. You cant find what in your style.css? Just copy and paste that css into the bottom of your style.css and you should be good to go

Comment: Ok now is fixed But my images are gone

Comment: @KBell yeah the issue occurs in what is supposed to be the footer of the page. The code looks generated to me so im not sure whats going on there.

Comment: @Aonghas M I dont know why images are gone when i add that css to my style.css in bottom of page

Comment: @AonghasM Seems that he uses some components (or CMS ?). And, yeah, I think downvote system is not that good. People should at least be forced to comment on the downvote. :/

Comment: @JosipValčić remove the CSS I gave you and ill take another look

Comment: @KBell I understand the basis behind it but his problem is probably solvable without a detailed question and he probably couldnt reproduce it. He doesnt deserve downvotes for that

Comment: @JosipValčić try my edited solution. If you still get issues then you will have to make the CSS more specific to the offending elements so that you dont catch unwanted elements

Comment: I add your code to my style.css but remove all the images i don't know what you mean sorry i am new on css. Can I give my CSS file

Comment: @JosipValčić have you tried my updated code? which uses margin: 0 instead of display: none?

Comment: @JosipValčić I cant see any of the code I gave you in that file however your site is still applying my old code not the updated version I gave you. If you are 100% sure you have updated the code on the site then force refresh (shift + f5 on chrome) a few times to clear your cache.

Comment: Can you check now i update code

Comment: Now situation is fixed for now thank you

Comment: @JosipValčić glad i could help